# Get SharePoint list items from another site collection with JSOM

Tags: javascript, permissions, sharepoint-hosted-app, jsom, app-permissions

I am using JSOM to get the list contents of a list which is located in another site collection than my app. For example, my app is hosted here: portal.contoso.com/sites/myapp and the list is on top level: portal.contoso.com/myList.

I get an 403 Forbidden error if I try to access the list with JSOM. The app has Tenant-administrator permissions.

Here is my code:

```
var serverUrl: string = "https://portal.contoso.com/";

try {
    var clientContext: SP.ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(serverUrl);
    var rootWeb = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(rootWeb);

    //Here it gets the SharePoint list e.g. portal.contoso.com/mylist
    var oList: SP.List = this.getAssetsList(clientContext);

    if (oList != null) {
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>'" +
        "<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
        this.sharePointCollectionListItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(this.sharePointCollectionListItems);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: It is the Javascript Object Model API does there exist something like SharePointOnlineCredentials? I only know it from C#. Do you have some code samples?

Comment: No there isn't, sorry :/

Comment: You may want to refer this article - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/1028/sharepoint-apps-javascript-object-model-jsom Here the app context and the host context are both being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access information in the host web using the Javascript Object Model you need to use an `SP.AppContextSite` object in conjunction with your `SP.ClientContext`

I see you're using TypeScript, which is awesome, so I'll post my answer with both TypeScript and the working Javascript; my comments will have some additional information and you can paste the JS directly into your browser dev tools:

**TypeScript**

```
/// <reference path="microsoft.ajax.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="SharePoint.d.ts" />

var appweburl: string,
    hostweburl: string,
    context: SP.ClientContext,
    appContextSite:  SP.AppContextSite;

JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); // this is an easy method to retrieve URL parameters...
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
// the context needs to be for the app web, so we can use get_current
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
// the appContextSite is for the hostweb,
// so we provide the hostweburl as the second parameter
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

// now we reference objects using the appContextSite
// but load and query using the context...
var list = appContextSite.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Site Assets");
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
context.load(items);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) {
    // success
    console.log(items.get_count());
}, function(sender, args) {
    //failure
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

**JavaScript** (just excludes type annotations for those of who like to copy/paste and see some results!)

```
var appweburl, hostweburl, context, appContextSite;
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); // this is an easy method to retrieve URL parameters...
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
// the context needs to be for the app web, so we can use get_current
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
// the appContextSite is for the hostweb,
// so we provide the hostweburl as the second parameter
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
// now we reference objects using the appContextSite
// but load and query using the context...
var list = appContextSite.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Site Assets");
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
context.load(items);
context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    // success
    console.log(items.get_count());
}, function (sender, args) {
    //failure
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

You can find more information on this technique in the [MSDN Article: Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_AccessHostweb), the host web stuff you're looking for is down at the bottom in the section titled "Access Objects in the Host Web".

Astute readers will notice that I do not initialize a `SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory` nor do I attach that factory to the `context`: while this methodology appears in most of the MSDN samples I've read, I have not found a single case where it is actually necessary. My *guess* (note the *emphasis*) is that you would need to use that pattern in the C# version of the Client Object Model, and since the Javascript Object Model is transpiled from the C# version the technique is likely carried over regardless.

Comment: Sorry, but the HostWeb variable contains only the url to the current site collection like "portal.contoso.com/sites/myappsite". But I need this: "portal.contoso.com" because the Assets library is stored on top level: "portal.contoso.com/assets". If I change the HostWeb variable to "portal.contoso.com" I get an "You have no permission" error.

Comment: @PhilippEger I'll do some testing later but I think you'll need to use the `SP.RequestExecutor` or a cross domain REST call to get data from a site above the one where the add-in is installed; more info here if you want to poke around on your own before I have time to take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx